# Tunnel apt traffic from private network through public to the internet

Tags: apt, private, tunnel

I've got 4 Servers under the following config:
Servers 1 and 3(Web Server, Mail server respectivelly):
NIC1: Public Network, Connected to the Internet
NIC2: Private Network, Communication between servers.

Servers 2 and 4 (DB and Backup Server):
NIC: Private Network, Communication between servers.

I'm trying to find a way to route the traffic of apt(only) from Servers 2 and 4 through one of the two servers connected on the public network to the internet so that I won't have to connect these two servers to the public network just for apt. Are there any ways to do this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a proxy server installed on either server 1 or 3, configured to allow connections to the sites in `sources.list` from the private network servers.  As a bonus, if you go with a caching proxy like squid or [`approx`](http://bethesignal.org/blog/2009/04/13/approx-package-caching-ubuntu-debian-lovers/) you'll use less bandwidth for downloading packages common to the servers.

For [regular web proxies like squid](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto/#Setting_up_apt-get_to_use_a_http-proxy), you can either set the `$http_proxy` environment variable before running apt, or edit your `apt.conf` file (if you're on Debian squeeze, it looks like the configuration is split up into different files in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/`, add a new file) and set

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://user:pass@yourproxyaddress:proxyport";
```

replace http with ftp if you're using ftp mirrors and an ftp capable proxy.

If you use approx, then you edit the clients' `sources.list` to point to your approx server instead of the original mirrors instead of setting a proxy in your shell or your apt.conf.

If you don't want to install a proxy, you can use ssh's port forwarding one of a few ways:

1: Change server 2/4's sources.list to use `http://localhost:8080/` for the mirrors. If you have more than one mirror host, you'll need to choose different ports (eg 8081) for each one.  On server2/4, enable `GatewayPorts` in `sshd_config`  Then, ssh from server 1 to server 2/4 using

```
ssh -R 127.0.0.1:8080:http.us.debian.org:80 server2
```

Use multiple -R commands (eg `-R 127.0.0.1:8081:security.debian.org:80`) if there are multiple mirrors to tunnel to.  As long as this ssh connection remains open, you'll be able to use apt.

2: Use ssh's "dynamic" SOCKS proxy and `tsocks` to provide SOCKS support for apt-get.  To do this, you will have to ssh "backwards" from server2 to server1 using

```
ssh -D 8080 server1
```

in one terminal then running [`tsocks apt-get update`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35223/syntax-for-socks-proxy-in-apt-conf) etc in another terminal.  You'll set the server and port information in `/etc/tsocks.conf` and the `tsocks` "wrapper" program will convert the normal http connections in apt to use the socks proxy provided by ssh.  This way you don't make any changes to sources.list.

Comment: I was hoping I wouldn't have to use a proxy just for that but unless there is nothing else I think I'll have to. Is there any other way, like using an ssh tunnel?

Comment: Alright, I'll try the last two options. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Using the remote SSH tunnel has worked well for me in this scenario. There's a brief tutorial [here](https://datawookie.dev/blog/2023/12/ssh-tunnel-remote-port-forwarding/).